# The 32-bit program cannot be executed with RISC-V Spike. Can't Execute 32-Bit Program on RV64 Hot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu, riscv32, spike

The following software has been built, installed, and passes. RISCV-GNU-TOOLS (both 64, 32bit), Spike, Riscv-PK (32bit).
If you try to execute the C language program with RISCV32 and execute it in Spike, you will get an error as follows. What should I do? The environment is ubuntu-20.04, 64 bit.

```
$ riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -static fib.c -o fib
$spike $riscvpk/bin/pk fib
Error: cannot execute 32-bit program on RV64 hart
```

What I did to make 32bit support.

```
sudo dpkg --add-arrhitecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6: i386 libncurses5: i386 libstdc ++ 6: i386
sudo apt-get Install gcc-multilib
```

```
#~/.bashrc
# RISC-V gnu-tools 64bit
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/riscv/bin
# RISC-V gnu-tools 32bit
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/riscv32/bin
# RISC-V spike
export RISCV=/opt/riscv32-tools/toolchain
export PATH=$PATH:$RISCV/bin
# RISC-V pk
export riscvpk=/opt/riscv32/bin/riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu
export PATH=$PATH:$riscvpk/bin
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask. Do you want to execute risc32 binary on Ubuntu amd64 ie. Ubuntu PC?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu PC.

Comment: I think you need https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/target-riscv.html

Comment: I installed ```apt-get install qemu-system-misc```, but it can't work with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For running 32 bit riscv binaries, you need to add `--isa=RV32IMAFDC` flag while running `spike` command. (Depending on your used extensions, e.g. also it can be `--isa=RV32IM`)

```
spike --isa=RV32IMAFDC $riscvpk/bin/pk fib
```